How to make MacBook EFI boot order permanent?
I have an old MacBook Air 2015. I recently installed Linux Ubuntu 2024 on it on a new ext4 partition. I can dual boot between macOS 12 and Ubuntu whenever I want by holding option key on startup.
Since all my family uses this Mac I want the boot priority to stay on macOS, so my family doesn't have to deal with dual booting options at startup.
I know I can set startup disk in macOS system preferences and I also use efibootmgr -o xxxx,yyyy on Linux to change this boot order, but the problem is any time I switch from macOS to Ubuntu from the startup disk chooser (by holding option key on startup), the boot order is set back to Ubutnu partition, so I have to change this order again after I finish my work.
Is there any way to change this behavior so that boot priority is always macOS no matter what the last used OS is?

In the EFI partition used by Ubuntu, there is volume. Holding down the option key at startup causes the Mac to boot to the Startup Manager. When you choose to boot Ubuntu, the Startup Manager boots using the file EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI. This file has the same contents as the file EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi. This EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI file causes the boot order to be set back to Ubuntu. You can change this by copying the EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file to the EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI file (thus overwriting this file).
Note that this fix can be undone if an update is made to GRUB. I more robust solution would be to install rEFInd to a new EFI partition and configure rEFInd to silently instruct the firmware boot from EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi.
